# Why am I getting two responses when I log my React state, setState by a fetch API request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm getting two responses from a console.log() of my state in React. The first is empty, and the second contains the data I'm trying to print.

> [] empty array
>
> [{…}] 0: {id: 1, date: "2011-07-01T10:30:30.000Z", name: "John"}
>   length: 1
>   **proto**: Array(0)

My code is like the following:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        session: []
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchSessionData();
}

fetchSessionData = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/sessions/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(session => this.setState({session:session});
}

render() 
{
    console.log(this.state.session);
    return(
        <div>
            <p>Hello world + {this.props.match.params.id}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If there was more than one javascript object in my response, I would also  also see something like:

> [] empty array
>
> [{…}] 0: {id: 1, date: "2018-11-01T10:30:30.000Z", name: "John"}
>   length: 1 **proto**: Array(0)
>
> [{…}] 0: {id: 1, date: "2018-11-01T10:30:30.000Z", name: "John"}, {id:
>   1, date: "2018-07-22T12:37:01.000Z", name: "Steve"}, length: 2,
>   **proto**: Array(0)

So on and so forth. I suspect this to be related to Promises or lifecycle, but have failed to find an answer. Furthermore, when I try to access state values like `this.state.session.id`, it returns undefined. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Your console log is in the render() function, so it fires every time the component renders (or re-renders).  Thats normal.  It renders when it first loads, then re renders when it finishes getting the data and updating the state.

Also, `this.state.session` is an array containing your json object.  So you will have to write something like `this.state.session[0].id`

Comment: Okay this helped my understanding of the problem a lot. I was looking right at an array (which now I understand that there is json inside of it at [0]) and wondering why I couldn't directly access it's values. Duh. 

Thank you for explaining this, as well as why the console log was being rendered twice - once before and after the data was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Every time render method is executed, you will see consoled statement.

**First Console:** When component is mounted.

**Second console:** When component is updated/re-rendered.

**When does component gets updated?**
 - when component receives any new inputs(props)
 - when component updates state of its own context
 - component does not updated state but calls forceUpdate

**If I execute setState multiple times will that print that n no of times?**
- no setState is async operation, React execute them in batches.